# Are bottom layer Curing settings automatically applied to everything touching the build plate?

Tags: slicing, chitu

When using Chitubox as a slicer for a resin print, will the bottom layer curing settings automatically be applied to any party of a model that is in contact with the build plate, or only to certain areas such as support rafts?

For example, if you were to place a gaming piece with a base flat on the build plate would the bottom of the base be cured using the bottom layer settings because it is in contact with the build plate, or with the same settings as the rest of the model?

Answer (score 1):

The bottom layer curing settings apply only to the number of layers configured in the settings panel appropriate to that option.

A gaming piece placed flat on the build plate would have curing times to match the above-noted settings for the specified number of layers. All subsequent layers would be cured with the (probably) faster/shorter curing time settings.

The contact with the build plate is presumed but not required. If one placed a model to be sliced in such a way that it was elevated by two layer heights (nominal 0.050 x 2 = 0.100 mm) but the settings provided for four bottom layer curing times, the first two of the lower layers of the elevated model would be cured for the bottom-setting times.

Consider that you have a basin attached to the build plate. The basin is four layers deep. Everything that would contact a fluid in that basin will be given the bottom layer exposure times.

Comment: So, if the bottom layer setting is set to 4, it doesn't matter whether those layers are part of the model or part of the support structure, so long as they are the lowest 4 layers?

Comment: That's correct. The lowest four layers, measured from the bed, will be given those settings. If the model is elevated in any manner, such as by tilting/rotating, it could take that portion out of the four layer area. See added edits to answer above.